# Running tests on IE driver with Jenkins installed on Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, internet-explorer, maven, jenkins

Currently I'm using Jenkins installed on Linux machine for automated testing Firefox and Chrome browsers.

My company want to start automated testing on IE. Is there any way to add virtual machine with Windows 7 os to Jenkins architecture (new node?) to run all tests from one Jenkins instance?

I want to have tasks with different builds :
- first to run tests on Chrome driver using mvn (works fine now)
- second to run tests on FF driver (works fine now)
- third to run tests on IE driver (need to be created)

If there is no way to do this should I prepare Windows machine with new Jenkins installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the hub option on your main selenium server

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub -hubHost localhost -hubPort 4444
```

And then on your windows machine (this is a chrome example as I am on my mac) do something like this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -hubHost <ip of hub> -hubPort 4444\
   -browser "browserName=chrome,maxinstance=2,platform=MAC" \
   -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="driver/chromedriver"
```

You will also need to download the iedriver to make it work [selenium downloads](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list)

You then connect to selenium through port 4444 (as a convention) on the main selenium server and it places requests accordingly